# Lua 5.1 dll error: equals sign expected on line 1?

Tags: dll, lua, multilingual, cross-language, lua-5.1

I have the following code:

```
int luaopen_Library()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Attempting to call `require "Library"` throws the following error:

```
Library.dll:1: '=' expected
```

How can I fix this? Please let me know if more information is needed; I am new to working with dlls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message is telling you that Lua is trying to load the dll as a Lua program. You have probably put the dll in the path given by `LUA_PATH`. You need to move it to the path given by `LUA_CPATH`.

Comment: I suspected that Lua might be trying to parse it like a Lua file, but I wasn't sure what could possibly be causing it. Nice catch.